# Best way to close ngbModal instances when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular app (ver 11) when back button is pressed or `location.back()` is called if `ngbModal` is active I want it to be closed. After research that I made I came up with something like this:

```
  modalService.activeInstances.subscribe((result: any) => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
      }
    })
  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onBrowserBackBtnClose(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
```

This didn't work like many other solutions I tried as mentioned on the internet. I want to decide if anyModal instances active or not. If it is, then close when back button is pressed; otherwise just go back.

Answer (score 1):

just add AngularLocator service and call it on ngOnInit() of any component you need to close the modal!

```
Angularlocater.onUrlChange(() => this.modalService.dismissAll());
```

Comment: I have almost 50 modals in the app so for all components implementing this doesn't make sense I need to find more generic solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I did

```
 lastModalInstance: NgbActiveModal;


  modalService.activeInstances.subscribe((activeModals: NgbActiveModal[]) => {
      if (activeModals.length > 0) {
        if (activeModals.length === 1) {
          history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
        }
        this.lastModalInstance = activeModals[activeModals.length - 1];
      }
      else {
        this.lastModalInstance = null;
      }
    })

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onBrowserBackBtnClose(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.lastModalInstance) {
      this.lastModalInstance.close();
    }
  }
```